# Access to a string in an ES6 Set object

Tags: javascript, object

I am using this library to find the email address in a string. 
https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-emails

I am struggling to access to the result.

```
getEmails(text); //=> Set {'sindresorhus@gmail.com', 'unicorn@rainbow.cake'}

typeof getEmails(text); // 'object'
```

How to get access to the first email address in this object?

Comment: IMO, `getEmails` returns `array`

Comment: @gyre Thanks for your comment. Your proposal returns undefined

Comment: @QuentinDel well what exactly is the contents of `text`? What happens if you `console.log(getEmails(text))`?

Comment: Can we see what the value of text is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `getEmails` actually returns an ES6 `Set` object, not an array:

**Get first email:**

```
// Option 1 (ugly but efficient)
let first = getEmails(text).values().next().value
// Option 2 (pretty but inefficient)
first = [...getEmails(text)][0]

console.log(first)
```

**Iterate over all emails:**

```
for (let email of getEmails(text)) {
  console.log(email)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wow that's pretty amazing, but good job spending more than the 2 seconds I spent looking at the test code :)

Comment: I made the same mistake initially . . . had to do a double take :)

Answer (score 1):

The README is misleading. The code returns an **array** of email addresses, so you can just access it by index:

```
var firstAddress = getEmails(text)[0];
```

*edit* — I'm wrong; the comment really *is* accurate, because it returns a Set instance! I'll leave this here and accept my downvotes in penance.

Comment: @QuentinDel did you notice he is pointing to the first element of array & not the whole like you did?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the values in the object via this:

```
var emails = getEmails();
for (email in emails) {
  console.log(emails[email])
}
```

Comment: That's certainly possible, though using `for ... in` for arrays is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Pointy This is an array now?

Comment: If you look at the actual code at the linked page, yes. That comment in the sample code just uses incorrect notation. Comments don't get checked for syntax :)

Comment: @BitByte Thanks for your proposal, but it seems not work on my side.